# i want to open a new window with passing id of students shows error in new window

Tags: laravel

I am successfully loading a page in a new window using `target="_blank"`,but the problem is the new window is loading with an error `NotFoundException`, when i try to pass id from the current window to new window

```
<a href="{{url('search/display/{$id}')}} target="_blank">{{$stud->name}}</a>

Route::get('search/display/{$id}','studcontroller@searchstud');
```

.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NotFoundException` is occurred for the routes not declared.
Check if you have created a route in `routes.php`.
Also verify the method to be `GET`.

If you have cached your routes earlier, try refreshing the route cache by using the command `php artisan route:cache`.

> NOTE: This route cache command will work only if you are not using any
>   closure route.

One more thing you can do to get proper link is, use `Url::to()` method supported by Laravel Illuminate.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the href attribute value. So, add `"`:

```
<a href="{{ url('search/display/{$id}') }}" target="_blank">{{$stud->name}}</a>
```

Comment: @sindhooritavm please show the HTML generated by Blade.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Alexey mentioned you where missing quotes, but you will also have to send the id parameter

```
<a href="{{ url('search/display/{$id}', $stud->id) }}" target="_blank">{{$stud->name}}</a>
```